# jQuery validate if input value has certain html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to give users of my site the option to add a youtube link using a form, so that the movie can be embedded on the site.

That means that they should paste something like this in the input field:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3Uj8aEfj6hg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I use jQuery (or Vanilla JavaScript) validation to check if the value in the input field does contain iframe tags?

Comment: youtube has its own embed link. just an hint.

Comment: the value you want to check is a plain text I guess. so you can search `iframe` or whatever you want in the input string.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous letting your users upload an iframe. Instead, just let them upload the embed ID (the 3Uj8aEfj6hg part) and build the iframe your side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .is('iframe') function to check.
http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you let the user paste the video URL instead of the whole iframe. By doing this, you would avoid some risks plus have a lot less data on your server.

1. User posts the URL
2. PHP removes everything but the video code
3. PHP inserts the code into your database

When a user later visits the site, you only need to load the code from the database and put into a template (the whole iframe code).

However, if you want to go with the iframe solution, then youäll have to go with javascript(see other answers).

Regards